# onmouseover not working not sure what is wrong

Tags: onmouseover

I have been working with the following fiddle and I cannot seem to get the onmouseover function to work properly!  can anyone tell me what is wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/hM25t/

```
<div id="box" onmouseover="alert();"></div>


function alert(){
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your jsFiddle, switch the drop down from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>` where you have jQuery 1.9.1 set on the left under **Frameworks & Extensions**. The function nextpoem is being put inside the jquery onload and that won't work. So by changing this it will work.

See this updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hM25t/4/